# MacBook display is fickering ONLY IN OS X / OK in Window 10 (Bootcamp)

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook Pro 15' (mid 2015) display is flickering ONLY IN OS X / perfectly FINE in Window 10 (Bootcamp)

It is OK when I 1.move the cursor / 2.play the video / 3.plug-in the HDMI cable.

I did clean re-install OS X Sierra to see if it can fix it, reset the PRAM (or NVRAM), reset the SMC, BUT none of them made any differences.

I also booted OS X in safe mode and it was fine, but after I booted in normal mode, still there is flickering.

I'm so confused because, as I said, it runs perfectly fine in Window 10 (bootcamp)

Is there any other option that I can try? or it is just a hardware issue that only the Bar can fix?

Comment: What do you mean that it's fine when you plug in an HDMI cable? Are you using an external display?

Comment: No, I don't use any external display, but I've found out that the display isn't flickering when I do so.

Comment: Is the HDMI cable connected to anything on the other end?

Comment: There is TV on the other end, but it is same with nothing on the other end.